# Windows 10 restart loses internet connection from USB modem

Tags: networking, windows-10, internet, usb-modem

After every restart/power-on of my newly built Windows 10 PC, I have to unplug/plug in my Huawei USB Modem for it to work. I know it's working between reboots because I have other Raspberry Pi devices connected via WIFI which still have service during those hours.

This was working initially for the first 3 weeks of my Windows 10 installation. One day I noticed that after restart, I had no internet (also indicated in the lower-right "notification area") that I had no internet connection. The solution is to either reboot the Huawei modem or to unplug the USB connection, which is what I have been doing now on a daily basis.

At first I wasn't sure what the problem was, so I assumed my routing tables were out of whack (I modify them occasionally, mostly to change the Metric because my main/fast internet is via the Huawei USB modem and my LAN is connected to multiple networks which either do not have internet service or have really slow internet).

Is there a reason why Windows can't use my USB modem without a reconnect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a different USB port on your PC.

Comment: That was easy! Apparently the front panel USB 3.0 ports have issues (otherwise they work just fine as far as I can tell, only this problem). I plugged into a USB 2.0 port on the front panel and after 4 reboots so far the problem hasn't happened again.

Comment: We got lucky, its not always easy!

Comment: I didn't even think of trying different ports because as stated, it worked fine for several weeks. Just one day it stopped working, so I assumed it was some Windows configuration gone awry (although perhaps it is).

Comment: That is why they call it Windows Plug and Pray.